# Find the probability mass function of Y considering Y=x^2

Tags: integration

Let X be a continuous random variable with probability density function
f (x) = 2x, 0 ≤ x ≤ 1.
 Let Y = X2. Find the probability mass function of Y and use it to find E(Y).

I stuck in finding pmf of y. Since x is continuous, can Y be discrete??

Answer (score 0):

If the density of $X$ is $f_X(x) = 2x$ for $0 \leq x \leq 1$ then the cumulative density function of $X$ is $\mathbb P( X \leq x) = x^2$.
Then, for $0 \leq t \leq 1$ we have,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P (Y \leq t ) &= \mathbb P(X^2 \leq t ) \\
&= \mathbb P (X \leq \sqrt{t} ) \\
&= t
\end{align*}
And the density of $Y$ is the derivative of $\mathbb P(Y \leq t)$ which is 1.
$Y$ is uniformly distributed and its expectation is $\int_0^1 tdt = 1/2$